# Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'number[]'. Unable to resolve error even after changing lib in tsconfig.json

Tags: javascript, typescript, methods, fetch-api

I'm using a function to fetch data from an API. Afterwards I'm trying to push part of that data (some id's) into an array, if that id is not already included. I wanted to use the .includes() method to check for this but I keep getting  "error TS2550: Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'number[]'."

This is the code below:

```
// Get data from API
const getFixturesData = () => {
    // Here I am fetching the data
    let domain: string = "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/fixtures?";
    let league: string = (document.getElementById("league")! as HTMLInputElement).value;
    let date: string = (document.getElementById("date-picker")! as HTMLInputElement).value;
    (async (url: string) => {
        const response: Response = await fetch(url, {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "x-rapidapi-host": "v3.football.api-sports.io",
                "x-rapidapi-key": "personal API key"
            }
        });
        return response.json();
    })(`${domain}date=${date}&status=FT`).then(value => {
    // Here I am parsing the data
        let fixtures: any[] = [];
        let competitions: number[] = [];

        if (league == "") {
            fixtures = value.response;
            for (let event in fixtures) {
                competitions.push(parseInt(fixtures[event].league.id));
            }
        } else {
            let allFixtures: any[] = value.response;
            for (let event in allFixtures) {
                if (allFixtures[event].league.id == league) {
                    fixtures.push(allFixtures[event]);
                    // Here is where I am trying to use .includes()
                    if (!(competitions.includes(parseInt(allFixtures[event].league.id)))) {
                        competitions.push(parseInt(allFixtures[event].league.id));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
```

Other solutions that I found online point to changing the lib in the tsconfig.json file. I tried multiple options but none of them worked. I get the same error. Here is the current configuration of the file. I only pasted the rows which are not commented out.

I'm using TypeScript 4.8.3 .
I'm a beginner in TypeScript so pardon any gross mistakes that you may observe.

```
{
   "compilerOptions":{
      "target":"ES2016",
      "lib":[
         "DOM",
         "ES2022"
      ],
      "module":"commonjs",
      "esModuleInterop":true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames":true,
      "strict":true
   }
}
```

Thank you for your time!